# Removing one table from django admin panel of sqllite database

Tags: sqlite, django-models

how can I remove a single table from django admin panel of sqllite database?

Answer (score 0):

#### To remove from admin dashboard

Remove the registering of the corresponding model in your admin.py file. Check out [The Django admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/).

#### To remove from database

Remove the corresponding class from your models.py file. Make migrations and migrate.
See [Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/) of the Django documentation.